# APP pushing on bluemix is failing

Tags: ibm-cloud

I did some modification in a working app,but during pushing it on bluemix cloud ,I am getting some error.
Below is the snippet:

```
Starting app resapp in org x / space y ... OK

-----> Downloaded app package (1.8M)

-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (9.2M)

-----> Buildpack Version: v1.4-20140908-1746


FAILED

Server error, status code: 400, error code: 170004, message: App staging failed in the

buildpack compile phase

TIP: use 'cf logs resapp --recent' for more information
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try again, googled and found that its an [intermittent issue](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/27842/announcement-intermittent-issues-with-application-pushstart-on-oct-3-2014/).

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks Mathew and Diwesh. It working now. I am able to push my app. Thanks A Lot

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I created my own buildpack from github and modified  https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/compile file. After modifying compile file, 'cf push' was failing with same error when I was trying to push my app in bluemix. The issue was with new changes in 'compile' file.

The error clearly says that "App staging failed in buildpack compile phase". So, there is an issue with compile file of buildpack. If you are using original buildpack that is not modified by you, then try after sometime; issue  may get solved. If, you have created your own buildpack by cloning the original from github, then verify the changes in 'compile' file. Yes, you should run 'cf logs resapp --recent' command to get details about error.

Answer (score 0):

Its an intermittent issue,i too faced this once, retry if happening again. It will work.